# Print periphery of a binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I want you to pick my code apart and give me some feedback on how I could make it better or more simple. This code will traverse peripheri  (clock and anticlockwise) in \$O(n)\$ just traversing the tree once.

```
public class PeriPheri {

    private TreeNode root;

    private static class TreeNode {
        TreeNode left;
        TreeNode right;
        int item;

        TreeNode(TreeNode left, TreeNode right, int item) {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
            this.item = item;
        }
    }

    private void printChild (TreeNode node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (node.left == null && node.right == null) {
            System.out.print(node.item + " ");
        }

        if (node != null) {
            printChild (node.left);
            printChild (node.right);
        }
    }

    private void leftAntiClock(TreeNode node) {
        if (node != null) {
            System.out.print(node.item +  " ");
            leftAntiClock (node.left);
            printChild (node.right);
        }
    }

    private void rightAntiClock(TreeNode node) {
        if (node != null) {
            printChild (node.left);
            rightAntiClock (node.right);
            System.out.print(node.item + " ");
        }
    }

    public void antiClockwise() {
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }

        System.out.print (root.item + " ");
        leftAntiClock (root.left);
        rightAntiClock (root.right);
    }


    private void rightClock(TreeNode node) {
        if (node != null) {
            System.out.print(node.item + " ");
            rightClock(node.right);
            printChild(node.left);
        }
    }

    private void leftClock(TreeNode node) {
        if (node != null) {
            printChild(node.right);
            printChild(node.left);
            System.out.print(node.item + " ");
        }
    }

    public void clockwise() {
       if (root == null) {
          return null;
        }
        System.out.print(root.item + " ");
        rightClock (root.right);
        leftClock (root.left);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you handle `NULL` in `private void printChild (TreeNode node) {` is confusing and potentially wrong. It would be nice if it could be handled in a consistent way across the different methods : either `if (n==null) return;` or `if (n!=null) { your_code }`. That would make everything easier to follow and that would make duplicated code easier to spot

I'd change the order of the argument in the constructor and define :
`TreeNode(int item, TreeNode left, TreeNode right)` AND `TreeNode(int item)` (initialising trees to `NULL`)

Answer (score 1):

I think that `printChild()` would be better named `printDescendantLeaves()`.  Also, `printChild()` always works left-to-right, which spoils your clockwise traversal.

For flexibility, consider taking a [visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) instead of hard-coding `System.out.println()` everywhere.  Alternatively, implement your traversal as an `Iterator` (which is admittedly tricky to do recursively since [Java doesn't support `yield`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1980953/1157100)).

"Periphery" is misspelled.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I do appreciate feedback on visitor pattern, but I am preparing strictly for interviews and doubt if visitor would be necessary on white board.

Comment: Demonstrating knowledge of the visitor pattern in an interview bumps you up to the next pay grade.  =)

Comment: good point sir. accepted.