# Reverse sublists of a linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, interval

This code reverses each consecutive *n* elements of a linked list, and for spare nodes, leaves them as they are.

For example, the linked list

> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7

for an interval of 3 should result in

> 3 -> 2 -> 1-> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 7

Note that 7 is left as it is as its spare.

I'm looking for code review, optimization and best practices.

```
   public class ReverseAtInterval<T> implements Iterable<T> {

        private Node<T> first; 
        private Node<T> last;
        private int size;


        public ReverseAtInterval(List<T> c) {
            for (T item : c) {
                add(item);
            }
        }

        public void add (T t) {
            final Node<T> l = last;
            final Node<T> node = new Node<T>(t, null);
            last = node;
            if (first == null) {
                first = node;
            } else {
                l.next = node;
            }
            size++;
        }

        private static class Node<T> {
            T item;
            Node<T> next;

            Node(T item, Node<T> next) {
                this.item = item;
                this.next = next;
            }
        }

        private static class ReversedFirstLastNextData<T> {
            Node<T> first;  // first node in the reversed list.
            Node<T> last;   // last node in the reversed list.
            Node<T> next;   // next node - this node is not a part of revered list

            public ReversedFirstLastNextData(Node<T> first, Node<T> last, Node<T> next) {
                this.first = first;
                this.last = last;
                this.next = next;
            }
        }


        private ReversedFirstLastNextData<T> reverse(Node<T> start, int n) {
            Node<T> prev = null;
            Node<T> ptr = start;
            Node<T> ptr1 = null;

            int ctr = 0;

            while (ctr < n) {
                ptr1 = ptr.next;
                ptr.next = prev;

                // advance forward.
                prev = ptr;
                ptr = ptr1;

                ctr++; 
            }

            return new ReversedFirstLastNextData<T>(prev, start, ptr);
        }



        public void reverseAtInterval(int n) {
            int ctr = 0;
            ReversedFirstLastNextData<T> prev = null;
            ReversedFirstLastNextData<T> current = null;
            Node<T> inputNode = first;

            while (ctr < (size/n)) {
                current = reverse(inputNode, n);

                if (prev == null) {
                    first = current.first;
                } else {
                    prev.last.next = current.first;
                }

                inputNode = current.next;
                prev = current;

                ctr++;
            }

            current.last.next = current.next;
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return new LinkedListItr();
        }   

        private class LinkedListItr implements Iterator<T> {
            private Node<T> prev;
            private Node<T> current;
            private int currentSize = 0;
            private int initialCapacity;

            public LinkedListItr() {
                this.current  = first;
                this.currentSize = 0;
                initialCapacity = size;
            } 


            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return currentSize < size;
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                if (initialCapacity != size) {
                    throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
                }

                if (!hasNext()) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
                currentSize++;
                prev = current;
                T item = current.item;
                current = current.next;
                return item;
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                if (initialCapacity != size) {
                    throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
                }
                if (!hasNext()) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
                prev.next = current.next;
                size--;
                initialCapacity--;
            }
        }


        public List<T> toArray() {
            List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
            Node<T> ptr = first;
            while (ptr != null) {
                list.add(ptr.item);
                ptr = ptr.next;
            }
            return list;
        }

    }


public class ReverseAtIntervalTest {

    @Test
    public void testEven() {
        ReverseAtInterval<Integer> rai = new ReverseAtInterval<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8));
        rai.reverseAtInterval(4);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(4, 3, 2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5), rai.toArray());
    }

    @Test
    public void testOdd() {
        ReverseAtInterval<Integer> rai = new ReverseAtInterval<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8));
        rai.reverseAtInterval(3);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8), rai.toArray());
    }

}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity : should `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8` lead to `3 -> 2 -> 1-> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 7 -> 8` (7 and 8 kept in the same order because we cannot form a triplet) or `3 -> 2 -> 1-> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 8 -> 7` (7 and 8 in reverse order as if they were the beginning of a triplet) ?

Comment: (7 and 8 kept in the same order because we cannot form a triplet)

Answer (score 6):

[You](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31717/print-periphery-of-a-binary-tree-critique-request/31720#comment51029_31720) and [@bazang](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/38001/bazang) are both very much into [interview-questions](/questions/tagged/interview-questions), and I think you would benefit greatly from answering each others' questions.  In fact, writing reviews would be more useful for preparing you for interviews than asking yet more questions, because:

- You get "no" choice in the matter of which question you are presented — just like in a real interview (assuming you commit yourself to answering whatever question comes your way).
- You practice communication skills, which are also important for interviewing.
- When you review someone else's work, you gain an appreciation for what goes on in the mind of the interviewer.

I bring this up now, because @bazang has tried to solve… [exactly the same problem](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/43464/9357)!

---

### Review

I agree with @Anonymous that your architecture is much too complicated, with too many inner classes.

It's odd that your `ReverseAtInterval()` constructor takes a `List<T>`, but you also offer the option to add individual elements via `public add(T)`.  The state problem was to reverse a list — so don't complicate things by offering to handle more stuff.

Passing the list to the `ReverseAtInterval()` constructor, then passing the interval to `.reverseAtInterval()` is also odd.  Calling `.reverseAtInterval()` will rearrange everything in the new order.  Allowing that mutated list to be further mutated if one calls `.reverseAtInterval()` again is more likely to be misused than useful.

If you try to reverse a list with an interval that is greater than the length of the input list, you get a `NullPointerException`.

`.toArray()` is misnamed.  I would expect it to return an array, not a `List`.

---

### Proposed Solution

Here's what I came up with.  (It's completely different from the solution for @bazang because you chose to base your interface on `java.util.List`.)

#### ReverseAtInterval.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class ReverseAtInterval<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    private final List<T> list;
    private final int interval;

    public ReverseAtInterval(List<T> list, int interval) {
        if (interval < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("interval < 1");
        this.list = list;
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new SublistReversingIterator();
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private class SublistReversingIterator implements Iterator<T> {
        // Iterator for the underlying list
        private final Iterator<T> underIter = ReverseAtInterval.this.list.listIterator();
        private final LinkedList<T> group = new LinkedList<T>();
        private Iterator<T> groupIter = group.iterator();

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return this.groupIter.hasNext() || this.underIter.hasNext();
        }

        public T next() {
            if (!this.groupIter.hasNext()) {
                if (!this.underIter.hasNext()) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }

                try {
                    for (int i = interval; i > 0; i--) {
                        this.group.push(this.underIter.next());
                    }
                    this.groupIter = group.iterator();
                } catch (NoSuchElementException exhausted) {
                    // For spare nodes, leave them as they are.  In other
                    // words, reverse the group again to restore the original
                    // order.
                    this.groupIter = group.descendingIterator();
                }
            }

            try {
                return groupIter.next();
            } finally {
                groupIter.remove();
            }
        }

        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

#### ReverseAtIntervalTest.java

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class ReverseAtIntervalTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> oneFive = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
        for (int interval = 1; interval <= 6; interval++) {
            for (int elem : new ReverseAtInterval<Integer>(oneFive, interval)) {
                out.print(elem); out.print(' ');
            }
            out.println();
        }
        // IllegalArgumentException expected...
        new ReverseAtInterval<Integer>(oneFive, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Architecture

This is much more complicated than it needs to be. There's no need to define a custom list class, unless you want to practice low-level destructive list-munging. Use one of the standard classes, like `java.util.LinkedList`.

It's simpler to attack this problem in two parts:

1. Divide the list into sublists.
2. Reverse them and concatenate them.

This can be quite simple — it's one line of Clojure:

```
(defn reverse-sublists [n xs] (mapcat reverse (partition n n nil xs)))
```

In Java you need to write the partitioning and concatenating code yourself, but this is still much simpler than defining your own list class.

### Comments on the custom-list implementation

If you do want to define a custom list class and reverse the list destructively, there are some things that could be done better:

`ReverseAtInterval` is misnamed. Its instances aren't reversals; they're linked lists, so it should be called something like `LinkedList` (or `SinglyLinkedList` to avoid colliding with `java.util.LinkedList`). Classes should be named for what their instances represent, not for the problem they solve.

`reverse` does something not obvious: it reverses the first `n` elements, not the whole list. This should be reflected in its name: something like `reverseFirstN` or `reversePrefix`.

`reverse` is an operation on a list, not on a `ReversedFirstLastNextData`, so it should not be a method of `ReversedFirstLastNextData`.

`ReversedFirstLastNextData` is unnecessary. `next` is always `last->next`, and `last` is always known to the caller (it was `start`), so `reverse` only needs to return `first`.

Variables in `reverse`:

- `ctr` should be a `for`-loop variable, to make it clear how it's updated. It's OK to call it `i`.
- `ptr1` can be declared inside the loop.
- `ptr` and `ptr1` should have meaningful names, such as `current` and `next`.

`ConcurrentModificationException` is usually about concurrent modification in multiple threads. That's not what you're using it for. AFAICT you're making sure `ReverseAtInterval.add` wasn't called, which can be done directly by making it private. If you still want to check to make sure you didn't mess it up, there's a simpler way:

```
assert initialCapacity == size;
```

The parentheses in `ctr < (size/n)` are redundant. Java arithmetic has higher precedence than comparisons. You can rely on this.

Comment: And even if arithmetic wouldn't have higher precedence than comparisons, removing the parenthesis would cause a compiler error and not unexpected results during runtime, as boolean divided by int makes no sense (in Java at least). Overall, a very nice review.